# Lucene filter to remove duplicates property

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

Is lucene filter which depends on some index for remove duplicates results or no hit more docs if one with this value is on results list  ? Or other way to achieve this condition ?

For example I have index:

```
1 | a | 2
2 | b | 3
3 | c | 2
4 | d | 4
```

If I have query which hit the "a", "b", "c", "d" I need to get distinct results on third column, so I expect:

"b", "d", ("a" OR "c" - only one, not important which) because "a" and "c" have same value on third column.

Comment: You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: Right, I explained more

Comment: Looks much better :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DuplicateFilter as described in [DuplicateFilterTest.java](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/lucene/contrib/queries/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/DuplicateFilterTest.java.shtml)

But the Filter has a Bug ([LUCENE-2348](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2348)) it only works if your index is stored in one segment. So you probably have to merge it using addIndexes and forceMerge(1) method.

Comment: The duplicate Filter is now Removed after LUCENE V6. Hence This Solution will not work anymore